# Silverlight Misc. Questions

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, data-binding

I am still new to silverlight and would like to ask few questions that relate to performing common tasks in silverlight that you used to do in asp.net programming (btw, I am using silverlight 4):

1. In silverlight, how do you access a public property on a user control in a databinding expression (without setting datacontext on the control itself)? For example, let us use a datagrid with ItemSource bound to some collection but you want to also databind to a value defined by a property your user control using the databinding expression, perhaps using 'Source' property. In asp.net you could access any public property/method using <%# expr #>.
2. In asp.net when a postback control was clicked and raised an event you were able to access the row in the event handler via event args and use FindControl() to find any control in the row. What's the equivalent process in silverlight?
   I know how to do get the row using DataGridRow.GetRowContainingElement() but then when I use row.FindName() I can't find another control in the same row by its name, I get null back. I found postings to do something like: grid.columns[colIndex] but that's error prone since you are using index to reference the column and then you have to get the cell content to access the control you after (cell.GetCellContent(row)). It is also not universal, the above illustrated how to do it in a datagrid.
3. In asp.net there's OnDataBind event you can handle on majority controls, is there something equivalent in silverlight?

Comment: 1) The datacontext is inherited from the parent.  If the datacontext of your user control is a collection, then any nodes in the XAML have access to that collection.  2) YourDataObject data = theGrid.SelectedItem as YourDataObject; 3) I dont' know what the onDataBind event does.  which is why this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: > 1) The datacontext is inherited from the parent. If the datacontext of your user control is a collection, then any nodes in the XAML have access to that collection. <-- I understand, how do you handle a scenario when you need to use current data context and also a public property defined on the user control?

Comment: > 2) YourDataObject data = theGrid.SelectedItem as YourDataObject <-- yes, that gives you the databound item but that doesn't answer the question how to find another control in selected row by name? I know you could say just do OneWay binding and modify the underlying data item and this will update all underlying controls but what if you just need to access the control for another reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. to create another property like the datacontext for your user control, you can create your own [custom dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx).
2. I would use the SelectionChanged event instead of the mouse click. it will easily tell you what row was "Added" when the user clicked the row.
3. At this time, no, you do not have a DataContext_Changed event in silverlight. BUT you can create your own by creating a custom dependency property, which will set the data context, and raise your own custom events. (not really sure why they didn't implement that originally, its in the WPF world).

*edit* to bind a property to the current control, use the following format:

```
Property="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=YourCustomProperty}"
```

for example, here is a textbox, where its text property is bound to its ID property:

```
<TextBox Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="97,105,0,0" Name="txtName" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"
             Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Name}"/>
```

Comment: OK, thanks, seems like I was looking for simpler solutions without writting dependency properties all over the place. For example, in WPF you can use Static keyword to access class statics and I was hoping there's a way to access instance properties from code behind without writting additional code.

Comment: I don't think you want to like Silverlight :)  It's pretty cool once it clicks.  But yes, you have to make a lot of dependency properties and MVC is more of a standard than MVVM.  There's still a lot of shooting from the hip in MVVM.

Comment: I want to like it :) To me simple common things like accessing properties freely is a great omission in a framework, looks like a step back from asp.net. Thanks for you comments.

Comment: I'm not quite following about accessing properties. you have access to all of the public properties of the user control within your markup. you just have to specify that you are using a relative source within the user control, and the path set to the public property you want.

Comment: Yes, the properties I refer to are my custom public CLR properties defined on the UserControl. Can you show me code snippet how to access these in XAML?

Comment: Can you show me snippet to make the textbox text bound to property on the user control that contains the textbox?

Comment: Did you make your property public? Your property should appear in your intelli-sense after you compile.

Comment: Yes, it is public. Can you show me code snippet (make the textbox text property to be bound to public property on the user control that contains the textbox) and I will experiment with that?

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you mean. I have first set the data context, then I can access the property via binding. I guess what I was looking for if it is possible to have a data context to one thing (other than the user control) but then access user control public property within that different data context - ie. you can freely change the data context as in asp.net unless you use the very limiting Source property.